# Function output wrong when using printf

Tags: c, function, error-handling, printf

```
printf("\n%d",NN+NE+ND+SD+SE+SS+E+D);
```

This is my functions when I call checkmoves in the main function they give me a value of 4 that it is correct but when I add the printf above to check some values to trying solve another problem the function checkmoves give me back 13 instead of 4.

Note that I call in main like `printf("\n%d", checkmoves(board,'o'));`

```
int count_flips_dir(char board[8][8],int line, char col,int delta_line,int delta_col,char color){
    int i;
    if(board[line+delta_line][col+delta_col]=='.'){
        return 0;
    }
    if (delta_line+line<=7 && delta_line+line>=0){
        if (delta_col+col<=7 && delta_col+col>=0){
            for(i=0;board[line+delta_line][col+delta_col]!=color;i++){
                line=delta_line+line;
                col=delta_col+col;
                if(board[line+delta_line][col+delta_col]=='.'){
                return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return i;
        
}
int flanked(char board[8][8],int line,char col,char color ){
    int NN = count_flips_dir(board,line,col,-1,0,color);
    int ND = count_flips_dir(board,line,col,-1,1,color);
    int NE = count_flips_dir(board,line,col,-1,-1,color);
    int SS = count_flips_dir(board,line,col,1,0,color);
    int SD = count_flips_dir(board,line,col,1,1,color);
    int SE = count_flips_dir(board,line,col,1,-1,color);
    int D = count_flips_dir(board,line,col,0,1,color);
    int E = count_flips_dir(board,line,col,0,-1,color);
    
    return NN+NE+ND+SD+SE+SS+E+D;
}
int checkmoves(char board[8][8],char color){
    int i;
    int count=0;
    char j;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        for(j=0;j<8;j++){
            if (board[i][j]=='.'){
                if (flanked(board,i,j,color)>0){
                    count++;                
                }
            }        
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: The function `checkmoves` can return a value between 0 and 64. So, why should it be 4 instead of 13? Both are valid values. Btw. `checkmoves` does not return the result of the expression `NN+NE+ND+SD+SE+SS+E+D`, so why do you compare this output to what `checkmoves` would return? Maybe i didn't understood the question.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük because it is calculating the number of possible moves so the  correct number of moves is 4 and not 13 so thats why and it is strange that the result change because of a printf so i don t know what is changing it

Comment: Are you saying that `checkmoves` gives you 4, but when you add `printf("\n%d",NN+NE+ND+SD+SE+SS+E+D);` (i assume in the function `flanked`), that you get the value 13? That (indeed) shouldn't be possible, unless there is something different going on (what we cannot see). You do not present a code, so that it would be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük  yeah thats exactly whaats apening i am trying to solve another problem so what i discover that when check moves variables i or j are 0 that some strange result apear don t know why

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: I suspect the problem stems from `board[line+delta_line][col+delta_col]` accessing outside array bounds.

Comment: but i test the bountrys of the array before caling it don't know why should be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `count_flips_dir` you test `if(board[line+delta_line][col+delta_col]=='.')` before checking that the initial move stays inside the board.

Then you test that the initial move stays inside the matrix to search for the color, but not the subsequent ones.

Furthermore, the function returns `i` uninitialized if the initial move goes outside of the board.

I am not sure what the function should return in this case, probably `0`.

Here is a modified version:

```
int count_flips_dir(char board[8][8], int line, int col,
                    int delta_line, int delta_col, char color) {
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        line += delta_line;
        col += delta_col;
        if (line < 0 || line >= 8 || col < 0 || col >= 8)
            return 0;
        if (board[line][col] == color)
            return i;
        if (board[line][col] == '.')
            return 0;
    }
    return i;
}
```